# Issue with drupal_add_css, can do it by nid but not by alias

Tags: theming

I am using the drupal_add_css function in my template.php file (Drupal 6) and this code works:

```
if (arg(0)=="node"&&arg(1)=="74" ) {
drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme', 'mythemename') . '/css/slider.css', 'theme');
  }
```

However if I use this code, it does not work.

```
if (arg(0)=="web-portfolio") {
drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme', 'mythemename') . '/css/slider.css', 'theme');
  }
```

I am wondering what I am doing wrong. (note "mythemename" is used in place of my actual theme name here and the actual aliased path is example.com/web-portfolio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if http://example.com/web-portfolio is the path alias for http://example.com/node/74, when you call `arg(0)` and Drupal is visualizing http://example.com/web-portfolio, the function doesn't return "web-portfolio" as you would think, but "node" because `$_GET['q']`, the variable used by `arg()`, is changed using the following code:

```
  // Drupal 6.
  // This code is part of drupal_init_path().
  if (!empty($_GET['q'])) {
    $_GET['q'] = drupal_get_normal_path(trim($_GET['q'], '/'));
  }
  else {
    $_GET['q'] = drupal_get_normal_path(variable_get('site_frontpage', 'node'));
  }
```

```
  // Drupal 7.
  // This is the code of drupal_path_initialize().
  if (!empty($_GET['q'])) {
    $_GET['q'] = drupal_get_normal_path($_GET['q']);
  }
  else {
    $_GET['q'] = drupal_get_normal_path(variable_get('site_frontpage', 'node'));
  }
```

The only way to get the path alias is to call [drupal_get_path_alias()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--path.inc/function/drupal_get_path_alias/7) as `drupal_get_path_alias($_GET['q'])` (Drupal 6), or `drupal_get_path_alias()` (Drupal 7).

If you are going to use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, remember that the string contained in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` can vary from "/web-portfolio" to "/?q=web-portfolio" (when the clean URLs are not enabled), or from "/dr61/web-portfolio" to "/dr61/?web-portfolio" (when Drupal is installed in the "dr61" directory of the web root directory). It could also change basing on which server is used to run Drupal (e.g. IIS versus Apache).

Comment: It's sounding like drupal_get_path_alias is the way to go. I tried this code but it did not work: `if (drupal_get_path_alias("node/{$vars['#node']->nid}") == 'web-portfolio') {
    drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme', 'mythemename') . '/css/slider.css', 'theme');
  } `

Answer (score 1):

arg() doesn't work with path as far as I know. I'm sure there are better aproaches to doing this, but I found a bit of a hack.

```
if(strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "web-portfolio")) {
  drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme', 'mythemename') . '/css/slider.css', 'theme');
}
```

I wouldn't use this however its not really the Drupal way. You are adding CSS for a slider, I guess that slide is made with views. You could just make your drupal_add_css call from the views template. That way you'll have it even if you change the path.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, I get the path this way

```
$path = drupal_get_path_alias(request_uri());
```

I use [request_uri](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/request_uri/) because it is best to program to the interface and not the specific implementation.  [drupal_get_path_alias](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--path.inc/function/drupal_get_path_alias/7) also gets called to handle cases where a page has multiple aliases, but global redirect isn't enabled.

You can then use `$path` for your test if you still want to do conditional includes.

Personally, I add all CSS and JS to all pages via the theme info file, or w/o a conditional in a `hook_init` if from a module.